# Document Library List Validation Error while uploading files to the folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-document-library, validation-list-items, column-validation

I'm using validation rule in document library (document set content type) which works fine while creating a list in the document library. However, when I try to upload document to the folder I receive the following error. Any ideas what can cause the problem?

No extra fields have been used during the validation process.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's the validation rule you set in the document library? Do you mean it works fine when create a document in the library, but get error when upload document to the document set?

Try to upload another type of document and check again.

Try to create a document in the document set and check the result.

Comment: The validation rule I have set in the document library, is blocking some fields to continue before the others are completed. The fields I have used are document set type fields not the original fields of document library itself. I can create another document inside the same document library without any problem but when I try to upload file into the document created within a document library, I can not upload any file. I tried but still having the same issue. When I remove validation rules, it works perfectly.

Comment: While trying to upload using mobile phone I get the following error. "The query string FileOffset is missing or invalid"

Comment: Just confirm: what's the mean of "upload file into the document created within a document library"?